# Why are these 1px thick divs different thicknesses?

Tags: html, css, line

Why are the two lines for this section of my website are different sizes when they're the same pixel height? Please check the snippet below.

What are other good methods of creating sections divider lines?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

p,
a,
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.seg-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(358deg, rgba(51, 82, 124, 1) 0%, rgba(18, 59, 114, 1) 100%);
  padding: 5% 0px;
}

.seg-2-sizeing {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

.seg-2-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.seg-2-text {
  flex-basis: 250px;
}

.seg-2-text p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.seg-2-line {
  height: 1px;
  background: hsl(240deg 19% 88%);
}
```

```html
<div class="seg-2">
  <div class="seg-2-line seg-2-sizeing"></div>
  <div class="seg-2-flex-container seg-2-sizeing"></div>
  <div class="seg-2-line seg-2-sizeing"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't find any issue.

Comment: No repro at my end either, either at 96dpi or 192dpi (200%).

Comment: I see it in Chrome. The top one in the "run snippet" is twice as thick or twice as bright as the bottom one

Comment: I reverted to the shorter version for you since it is not visible in the larger text

Answer (score 1):

try using `<hr>` tag, and apply CSS to that

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use a border to do horizontal rules?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

p,a,h1,h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.seg-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(358deg, rgba(51,82,124,1) 0%, rgba(18,59,114,1) 100%);
  padding: 5% 0px;
}

.seg-2-sizeing {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

.seg-2-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.seg-2-text {
  flex-basis: 250px;
}

.seg-2-text p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.seg-2-line {
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(210deg 18% 87%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="seg-2">
  <div class="seg-2-line seg-2-sizeing"></div>
  <div class="seg-2-flex-container seg-2-sizeing">
    <div class="seg-2-text">
      <h2>Secure cleanup with one click</h2>
      <p>HI, HI</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg-2-line seg-2-sizeing"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it as well but would also remove both the `seg-2-line`'s completely and just have a border on the `flex-container`. For this to look right you would also have to change the container `padding: 15px auto` into a `margin: 15px auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the hr which is what you wanted?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}


hr { width: 60vw;  }

p,
a,
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.seg-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(358deg, rgba(51, 82, 124, 1) 0%, rgba(18, 59, 114, 1) 100%);
  padding: 5% 0px;
}

.seg-2-sizeing {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

.seg-2-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.seg-2-text {
  flex-basis: 250px;
}

.seg-2-text p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seg-2">
  <hr/>
  <div class="seg-2-flex-container seg-2-sizeing"></div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```